# Selenium opens a blank page, how to retry

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am writing selenium framework with multiple environment support, and lower envs are slower and sometimes fail to load a page - completely blank page is loaded after 30s.
How can I add a global retry mechanism to try again in such scenario, other than modyfing every method that opens new page.

What such mechanism should do, refresh the page and continue? I have no good ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build on dynamic function which includes pageload strategy and  check if the document ready state is complete or not if these two conditions aren't met then u can reiterate the initialization process.

void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition) wd ->
((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}

Comment: Do you add this function to your every "isAt" page checker function?

Comment: Yes we can do that or we can build one listener and keep polling through test runs..